# How to hide subcategory posts in main category

Tags: posts, customization, categories

I want to show in my Taxonomy only posts which are in Main Category and Subcategories links - but i need to hide posts which are in Subcategories in main category. Do you know how can i do it?

This is simillar situation: [Exclude sub category posts from category display](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/136486/exclude-sub-category-posts-from-category-display)

Comment: The link you posted is exactly the same situation. Have you tried any of the 7 answers posted there?

Comment: It doesnt work for me:(